# MariaDB user with global privileges has no access to database

Tags: mariadb

My issue is the following:

I have created a user in MariaDB who has global privileges with the following command:

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;`

The user can successfully create a new database, lets call it "newdb".

The issue is that the user does not have access to this database, and when trying to give privileges to himself on the database that he created with the command:

`` GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `newdb`.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; ``

I get a 1044 error (access denied for user).
What is wrong here? A user that has global privileges to everything should have access to all databases, right?

Later I want to create another user with user, and give that user rights to the newly created database

```
CREATE USER 'anotheruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `newdb` . * TO 'anotheruser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

I'm specifically trying to avoid using root to solve this, because this user will be used by an external software.

Any help would be appreciated.

mariadb version is 11.1.2

I have tried basically everything I have found so far, the only thing that I can think of now is either there is some kind of limitation that is not mentioned in the MariaDB documentation, or that this is a bug

Comment: Look at `\s` on the prompt to see which user you are connected as. And `show grants`

Comment: I am connected as 'user'@'localhost', typing SHOW GRANTS will bring up the following:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*0B31D4D016940C363120844CA69448DFE814CA25' WITH GRANT OPTION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem. The mariadb is running inside a docker container, and other containers try to access it. Docker creates a network for these containers where instead of an IP address the communication between the containers happens via the name of the container. The port that is open for the mariadb container is opened towards localhost, but when the database is accessed from another container the localhost is entirely skipped and direct connection is made, therefore the connection does not happen as 'user'@'localhost', but instead as '%'.